# sqlite3. Сравнить строку с числом

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

```
@Bot.command()
 async def buymoney(ctx):
     if cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)) < 0:
         await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "У вас недостаточно репутации для покупки 50 **:leaves:**"))
     else:
          cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET rep = rep - 1 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
          cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + 50 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))

          connection.commit()

          await ctx.message.add_reaction('')
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу сравнить строчку из sqlite3 с числом.
Мне выдает ошибку.
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id))[0], вроде

Comment: тогда выдает это  'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id))
result = cursor.fetchone()
result[0] # С этим сравнивайте
```

После `cursor.execute` вы забыли сделать `fetchone` или `fetchall`

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как будет это выглядеть. Совсем недавно познакомился с sqlite3. Я не совсем понимаю, что с чем сравнивать.

Comment: Вы хотите получать репутацию у всех пользователей и её сравниваете с нулём. Вы в cursor.execute должны делать не только WHERE server_id, но и еще user_id (WHERE server_id = {}, user_id = {}). И тогда данные данные в result будут только выбранного пользователя в виде кортежа, с которым вы можете взаимодействовать выбирая элемент в нём (через [...])